# ExtJS--dynamically changing column chart y-axis maxValue/range

Tags: extjs

I have a chart which has a maxValue for y-axis hardcoded to 100. Is there a way I can make this dynamic? Because my counts normally are ones and tens but can go up to thousands or even ten thousands. If thats the case then the column wont even render and chart will be blank since maxValue is only 100.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I inspected my chart object in debugger and saw I have access to its axes and digged down further and got access to maximum config.

```
this.getChart().axes.items[0].maximum = maxValHere;
```